# Is it advisable to (further) limit the size of forms when using golang?

Tags: go

I searched around and as far as I can tell, POST form requests are already limited to 10MB (http://golang.org/src/net/http/request.go#L721).

If I were to go about reducing this in my `ServeHTTP` method, I'm not sure how to properly do it. I would try something like this:

```
r.Body = http.MaxBytesReader(w, r.Body, MaxFileSize) 
err := r.ParseForm()
if err != nil {
     //redirect to some error page
     return
}
```

But would returning upon error close the connection as well? How would I prevent having to read everything? I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26393261/2202497, but what if content length is not set and in the middle of reading I realize that the file is too big.

I'm using this as a security measure to prevent someone from hogging my server's resources.

Comment: The way you're proposing looks fine. Won't read everything, or the stdlib's 10MB limit would be ineffective too. A huge POST with no Content-Length is not going to be generated by most browsers/user agents, and I think hanging up on the request is a reasonable response if it happens.

Comment: I think this is premature optimization. Until you notice that you are getting unusually high traffic, you should just leave it as simple as you can. I'm sure you have plenty of other higher priority tasks you need to complete. :P

Comment: @Populus I've realized. I'm not too concerned about it at the moment. I'll keep up the question up though.

Comment: Check the documentation carefully, it isn't actually a 10MB limit. "The whole request body is parsed and up to a total of maxMemory bytes of its file parts are stored in memory, with the **remainder stored on disk in temporary files**."

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The correct way to limit the size of the request body is to do as you suggested:

```
r.Body = http.MaxBytesReader(w, r.Body, MaxFileSize) 
err := r.ParseForm()
if err != nil {
 // redirect or set error status code.
 return
}
```

MaxBytesReader sets a [flag on the response](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/3c4be235be8dcd124fe8d536af3e422729a85785/src/net/http/server.go#L340-L347) when the limit is reached. When this flag is set, the server does not read the remainder of the request body and the server closes the connection on return from the handler.

If you are concerned about malicious clients, then you should also set [Server.ReadTimeout](http://godoc.org/net/http#Server.ReadTimeout), [Server.WriteTimeout](http://godoc.org/net/http#Server.WriteTimeout) and possibly [Server.MaxHeaderBytes](http://godoc.org/net/http#Server.MaxHeaderBytes).

If you want to set the request body limit for all of your handlers, then wrap root handler with a handler that sets the limit before delegating to the root handler:

```
 type maxBytesHandler struct {
     h http.Handler
     n int64
 }

 func (h *maxBytesHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
     r.Body = http.MaxBytesReader(w, r.Body, h.n) 
     h.h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
 }
```

Wrap the root handler when calling ListenAndServe:

```
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", &maxBytesHandler{h:mux, n:4096))
```

or when configuring a server:

```
s := http.Server{
    Addr: ":8080",
    Handler: &maxBytesReader{h:mux, n:4096},
}
log.Fatal(s.ListenAndServe())
```

There's no need for a patch as suggested in another answer. MaxBytesReader is the official way to limit the size of the request body.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: As others cited MaxByteReader is the supported way. It is interesting that the default reader is instead, limitreader after type asserting for max byte reader.

<strike>Submit a patch to the Go source code and make it configurable! You are working with an open source project after all. Adding a setter to http.Request and some unit tests for it is probably only 20 minutes worth of work. Having a hardcoded value here is a bit clunky, give back and fix it :).</strike>

You can of course implement your own `ParseForm(r *http.Request)` method if you really need to override this. Go is essentially BSD, so you can copy paste the library ParseForm and change the limit, but thats a bit ugly no?