# golang - which function for uploading large files

Tags: forms, go, upload

In go there are different ways to read a file sent with a multipart form

`r.FormFile("file")`

`r.MultipartReader()`

`r.ParseMultipartForm(size)`

and I partially understand the difference between them, however which is it the best for handling large files (~1GB)?

And, which is the one that uses less memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.ParseMultipartForm

> ParseMultipartForm parses a request body as multipart/form-data. **The whole request body is parsed and up to a total of maxMemory bytes of its file parts are stored in memory, with the remainder stored on disk in temporary files.** ParseMultipartForm calls ParseForm if necessary. After one call to ParseMultipartForm, subsequent calls have no effect.

You can therefore control the maximum memory usage by calling `r.ParseMultipartForm(max)`, and you can control the total amount read from the request by using [`http.MaxBytesReader`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#MaxBytesReader).

Also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28292505/556573